# Create scripts in seperate file for each object with correct ordering

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

In MSSMS you can create scripts for each object in a different file. That's awesome.
But if you want to actually run the scripts, you'll have to determine the order of the scripts or you will run into referential keys.

Is there a way to have the files generated with an ordering number so they can be executed alphabetically?
Alternatively: is there a way to automatically determine the order somehow?

Comment: In many realistic schemas, no such order can exist - you need to separate the creation of (tables, primary and unique keys) from the creation of foreign keys - then run all of the first set before attempting the second.

Comment: Then how do I auto generate scripts for the tables and references in different files?